# Firefox Pagespeed reporting image size can be reduced on ASP.NET/GDI encoded image?

Tags: asp.net, encoding, gdi

I have a method that takes a bitmap image: `foo(Bitmap bmp){}`

Im calling `bmp.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams);`

Essentially `encoder` is set with the following pseudo code:

```
foreach (var _encoder in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
{
  if (_encoder.mimetype=="image/png")
  {
   encoder = _encoder;
   break;
  }
}
```

And EncoderParameters is basically

```
 using (EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters(1))
            {
                encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
                ...
                ...
            }
```

Whether the image type is a jpeg or png, pagespeed still says something along the lines of:

> Losslessly compressing xyz.png
>   could save 207B (44% reduction). See
>   optimized version or  Save as.

Can anyone offer any insight? I realise that this is abit of a specialized topic so this is a bit of a stab in the dark.

Comment: All I know is the GDI libraries being as old as they are perform very badly in todays web environment. To get decent results you have to output to PNG but the file size is massive for example if I use photoshop to output the same file it optimises soo much better.. 

I have implemented ColorQuantizing with the GDI libraries (not sure if this is the original article: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/gdi/article.php/c3677, which gives you better, not perfect results).

It's going to be better outputting your own static graphics over anything dynamic using GDI+

Comment: So in my application I was outputting to PNG, but the file size is massive, it's like they are totally uncompressed PNG's.. 

I have found using ColorQuantizing with GDI outputting to gif or jpeg is good enough, but not as good as the PNG option in terms of quality but file size has gone from 200-300kb per 800pxX800px image to 80-90kb